# Are all exact Lagrangian spheres, vanishing cycles?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry, lagrangian-submanifolds, fukaya-category, vanishing-cycles

Let $\pi: E \to D$ be an exact Lefschetz fibration with corners (fibers with boundary)over the disk. Fix a point $\theta \in \partial D$ and consider the fiber $F_\theta = \pi^{-1}(\theta)$ over that point. Then the vanishing cycles in $F_\theta$ are exact Lagrangian spheres. By vanishing cycle we mean a sphere embedded in the fiber that degenerates to a point along a path that joins $\theta$ with a critical point of $\pi$.

As pointed out by Paul Seidel in his book, the fact that vanishing cycles are exact Lagrangian spheres is trivial except when $\dim E = 4$ (see 16b, page 221 of "Fukaya categories and Picard-Lefschetz theory"). A bit later in that same chapter is pointed out that any exact Lagrangian sphere in an exact Symplectic manifold $F$ appears as the vanishing cycle in some Lefschetz fibration that has $F$ as one of its fibers.

Now my question: assume $\dim E = 4$ (I'm not sure if this is relevant but maybe it simplifies it in terms of the framings of the Lagrangian spheres). Assume also that we fix the Lefschetz fibration $\pi: E \to D$. Suppose that the set of vanishing cycles generates the homology $H_1(F_\theta)$. Let $V \subset F_\theta$ be an exact Lagrangian sphere (in this case, a simple closed curve).

> Is $V$ a vanishing cycle? That is, does necessarily exist a path in $D$ joining $\theta$ with some critical point that has $V$ as its vanishing cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not necessarily true. In fact, this is *never* the case if $E = B^4$, and $F$ has connected boundary and genus $g \ge 2$.

Since $H_1(E) = 0$, the vanishing cycles span $H_1(F)$.
An Euler characteristic computation tells you that the Lefschetz fibration has $2g$ critical points.
Choosing a set of paths in $D$ from a basepoint to the critical points, we get a set $C$ of $2g$ vanishing cycles, and Dehn twists along them generate a subgroup $\Gamma$ of the mapping class group of $F$. Every other vanishing cycle is in the orbit $\Gamma\cdot C$, so that in particular the subgroup generated by all vanishing cycles is $\Gamma$ itself. But Humphries proved that the mapping class group of a surface of genus $g \ge 2$ and with one boundary component cannot be generated by fewer than $2g+1$ Dehn twists, so $\Gamma$ is a proper subgroup of the mapping class group of $\Gamma$, so there has to be a simple closed curve which is not a vanishing cycle. (I believe that the reference for Humphries' result is: Humphries, *Generators for the mapping class group*, 1979.)

The torus knots $T(2,2g+1)$ display this phenomenon very concretely: there is a Lefschetz fibration on $B^4$ whose fibres have genus $g$ and whose boundary has an open book with binding $T(2,2g+1)$. (This comes from Morsifying the function $f\colon \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ mapping $(x,y)$ to $x^2+y^{2g+1}$.) The surface of genus $g$ is a plumbing of $2g$ bands, and the vanishing cycles can be taken to be the cores of these bands. But the subgroup they generate is a proper subgroup of the mapping class group: the proof by authority is that there is a well-known presentation that includes these generators but also has an extra Dehn twist.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. Although I’m not sure I understand it. I know there are simple closed curved that are not vanishing cycles. My questions is if the exact Lagrangian spheres are vanishing cycles (or not). You require for this that the restriction of the Liouville form to the sphere is exact (this is the definition of exact lagrangian). Maybe I should rewrite the question to make it more explicit.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the exactness condition. I think that the following works, but I'd need to double-check: if you take a curve $V$ that is not in the set of vanishing cycles I described, my guess is that you can either deform the Liouville form or isotope $V$ so that $V$ becomes exact, and then the argument works. (The argument in the answer is insensitive to isotopies.)

Comment: In the question we fix the exact fibration (and so also the Liouville form on each fiber). Are you suggesting that every simple closed curve is isotopic to an exact Lagrangian circle?

Comment: I'm suggesting it, just not in a very convinced way. What you can do, following the example of $T(2,2g+1)$, is to construct a larger Lefschetz fibration with $2g+1$ critical points with vanishing cycles all the generators in the Humphreys presentation, and then take a sub-disc corresponding to the $2g$ vanishing cycles coming from $T(2,2g+1)$. In this way the "extra" vanishing cycles is a vanishing cycle of some Lefschetz fibration, so it's exact.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still not very convinced about your first suggestion but this second construction does it. So one can use Lemma 16.9 from Seidel's book to construct an exact Lefschetz fibration that "contains" a morsification of the $A_{2g}$ singularity and some extra vanishing cycle. Now the geometric monodromy group of the bigger fibration is the whole mapping class group of the fiber (by Humphries result) but the smaller one is not because the argument about the presentation you gave.

Comment: Just a little comment. Observe that this argument on the presentation must be wrong for $g = 1$ where the Dehn twists around the two vanishing cycles of the plane curve singularity (the usual cusp) do generate the whole mapping class group. I need to check that this argument actually holds for higher genus.

Comment: Yes, for $g=1$ this does not work. That's why I needed to assume $g \ge 2$ from the get-go.